# length() is showing 0 in c++ (although string has a content stored in it)

Tags: c++

I was writing this code for storing one string content into another string using a loop. (In the following code)After execution of for loop, string str1 contains the string str content but why then str1.length() is showing 0(Zero) that's what I'm not able to figure it out why?

```
string str;
str = "1234";
string str1;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
    str1[i] = str[i];
}
cout << str1.length() << endl;
```

Comment: `str1[i] = str[i];` is _undefined behavior_. You cannot dereference not yet allocated memory from an uninitialized `std::string`.

Comment: `str1` has no length, so all the `str1[i]` are out of bounds. And you are trying too hard, when `str1 = str;` would just work.

Comment: The string doesn't magically resize by itself if you are trying to access out of range element

Comment: `string str = "1234"; str1 = str;` Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first resize your new string `str1`. This is because you are accesing areas of memory outside of the string (you are looking where the string isn't, in a way). The `resize` makes the string large enough to fit your new string.

Try this:

```
string str;
str = "1234";
string str1;
str1.resize(str.length());  // NEW LINE
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
    str1[i] = str[i];
}
cout << str1.length() << endl;
```

But if you just want to copy the string, you can use `str1 = str`

Comment: @VikasChaurasiya It seems that Solver's answer answers your question.
If so, then please mark it as your accepted answer.